# How does regex {m,n}? work in Python?

Tags: python, regex

From the Python documentation of the `re` module:

> {m,n}?
>
> Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as few repetitions as possible. This is the non-greedy version of the previous qualifier. For example, on the 6-character string 'aaaaaa', a{3,5} will match 5 'a' characters, while a{3,5}? will only match 3 characters.

I'm confused about how this works.  How is this any different from `{m}`?  I do not see how there could ever be a case where the pattern could match more than `m` repetitions. If there are `m+1` repetitions in a row, then there are also `m`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered setting up some test cases and experimenting?  You should do this first, then if you are confused by the results, post them in your questions with what you would expect

Comment: It's just a range on the number of repetitions you want to match instead of an exact number.

Comment: Note that `{m,n}` and `{m,n}?` (note the `?`) are subtly different. Reach for 'regex non-greedy' for more info.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, I understand the difference between `{m,n}` and `{m,n}?`  I was having trouble understanding the difference between `{m}` and `{m,n}?`

Comment: I'm confused as to why there's an answer with 6 upvotes that doesn't answer the question

Comment: @dsg I think the answer misunderstood the question, but his answer is nonetheless easily extended to the correct answer.

Comment: @Daniel,the docs for `{m}` states  *Specifies that exactly m copies of the previous RE should be matched*  for `{m,n}?` *Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as few repetitions as possible.*, what part of that do you not understand?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was having trouble understanding how `{m,n}?` which tries to capture the _minimum_ number of repetitions possible in the range from `m` to `n` is different from `{m}`. After reading the answers, I understand now.

Answer (score 7):

Whereas, it is true that a regex solely containing `a{3,5}?` and one with the pattern:  `a{3}` will match the same thing (i.e. `re.match(r'a{3,5}?', 'aaaaa').group(0)` and `re.match(r'a{3}', 'aaaaa').group(0)`
will both return `'aaa'`), the differences between the patterns becomes clear when you look at patterns containing these two elements.  Say your pattern is `a{3,5}?b`, then `aaab`, `aaaab`, and `aaaaab` will be matched.  If you just used `a{3}b` then only `aaab` would get matched.  `aaaab` and `aaaaab` would not.

Look to Shashank's answer for examples that flush out this difference a little more, or test your own.  I've found that this [site](http://pythex.org/) is a good resource to use to test out python regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

I think the way to see the difference between the two is through the following examples:

```
>>> re.findall(r'ab{3,5}?', 'abbbbb')
['abbb']
>>> re.findall(r'ab{3}', 'abbbbb')
['abbb']
```

Those two runs give the same results as expected, but let's see some differences.

Difference 1: A range quantifier on a subpattern lets you match a large range of patterns containing that subpattern. This lets you find matches where there normally wouldn't be any if you used an exact quantifier:

```
>>> re.findall(r'ab{3,5}?c', 'abbbbbc')
['abbbbbc']
>>> re.findall(r'ab{3}c', 'abbbbbc')
[]
```

Difference 2: Greedy doesn't necessarily mean "match the shortest subpattern possible". It's actually a bit more like "match the shortest subpattern possible starting from the leftmost unmatched index that can possibly start off a match":

```
>>> re.findall(r'b{3,5}?c', 'bbbbbc')
['bbbbbc']
>>> re.findall(r'b{3}c', 'bbbbbc')
['bbbc']
```

The way I think of regex is as a construct that scans the string from left to right with two iterators that point to indices in the string. The first iterator marks the beginning of the next possible pattern. The second iterator goes through the suffix of the substring starting from the first iterator and tries to complete the pattern. *The first iterator only advances when the construct determines that the regex pattern cannot possibly match a string starting from that index.* Thus, defining a range for your quantifier will make it so that the first iterator will keep matching sub-patterns beyond the minimum value specified *even if the quantifier is non-greedy*.

A non-greedy regex will stop its second iterator as *soon* as the pattern can stop, but a greedy regex will "save" the position of a matched pattern and keep searching for a longer one. If a longer pattern is found, then it uses that one instead, if it's not found, then it uses the shorter one that it saved in memory earlier.

That's why you see the possibly surprising result with 'b{3,5}?c' and 'bbbbbc'. Although the regex is greedy, it will still never advance its first iterator until the pattern match fails, and that's why the substring with 5 'b' characters is matched by the non-greedy regex *even though its not the shortest pattern matchable*.

Answer (score -1):

SwankSwashbucklers's answer describes the greedy version. The `?` makes it non-greedy, which means it will try to match as few items as possible, which means that

```
`re.match('a{3,5}?b', 'aaaab').group(0)` # returns `'aaaab'`
```

but

```
`re.match('a{3,5}?', 'aaaa').group(0)` # returns `'aaa'`
```

Comment: re.match will match both strings whether its greedy or not. This answer is misleading and serves to confuse IMO. A better idea would be to point out the difference between `a{3,5}?` and `a{3,5}` patterns against string 'aaaaaa'.

Comment: thanks. now corrected, and there was a second mistake that is also corrected

Comment: It still doesn't really show the difference between non-greedy and greedy. I suggest showing `re.findall(r'a{3,5}?', 'a'*6)` and `re.findall(r'a{3,5}', 'a'*6)` The first will find two matches, the second, only one.

Comment: yes it does. the first case matches 4 a's, the second 3 a's. Both strings have 4 a's

Comment: The OP is asking about the difference between `{m}` and `{m,n}?`

Answer (score -2):

let say we have a string to be searched is:
                     str ="aaaaa"

Now we have patter = a{3,5}
The string which it matches are :{aaa,aaaa,aaaaa} 
But here we have string as "aaaaa" since we have only one option.

Now lets say we have pattern = a{3,5}?
in this case it matches only "aaa" not "aaaaa".

Thus it takes the minimum items as possible,being non greedy.

please try using online regular Expression at :https://pythex.org/

It will be great help and we check immediately what it matches and what it does not